# Ajax driven select in Grails not refreshing selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, gsp

I've implemented an ajax select using the Grails [site example](http://www.grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP) code where the user selects a country and the city field is updated. I'm using jQuery instead of Prototype.

After selecting a new country, the city field does not change but when the user clicks on the the city select, it shows only the new cities and the user can select one of them.

The city select list is being updated but the currently displayed value is not automatically updated.

This is the view:

```
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <g:select
                    optionKey="id" optionValue="name" name="country" id="country"
                    from="${com.TourneyCard.Country.list(sort:'name')}" value="${homeCountry.id}"
                    onchange="${remoteFunction(
                        action:'ajaxGetCityJSON',
                        params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)',
                        onSuccess:'updateCity(data);')}">
            </g:select>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label class="ui-select" for="city">City</label>
            <g:select name="city" id="tee" data-native-menu="true"
                      optionKey="id" optionValue="name" from="${homeCities}">
            </g:select>
        </div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<g:javascript>
    function updateCity(data) {
        if (data) {
            var rselect = document.getElementById('city')

            var l = rselect.length

            while (l > 0) {
                l--
                rselect.remove(l)
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var tee = data[i]
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.text = city.name
                opt.value = city.id
                try {
                    rselect.add(opt, null) // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
                }
                catch(ex) {
                    rselect.add(opt) // IE only
                }
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        var zselect = document.getElementById('city')
        var zopt = zselect.options[zselect.selectedIndex]
        ${remoteFunction(
          action: "ajaxGetCityJSON",
          params: "'id=' + zopt.value",
          onSuccess: "updateCity(data)")}
        }
</g:javascript>
```

Comment: Great question, but stylewise, I would avoid using a lower-case 'L' as a variable in *any* programming language.  In many fonts it is quite difficult to discern the difference between l and 1.  
1 = l, and even | and l and 1.  
`1 = l`

Comment: You can try this aproach [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450294/grails-select-remotefunction-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450294/grails-select-remotefunction-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after you have added in the new options to the city select list.

> rselect.selectedIndex = 0

This *should* reset the selected option within the list and force the browser to re-display the list without user intervention.

Comment: Setting the selectedIndex value does change which value is selected but it is still not refreshing the display. For instance, if selectedIndex is set to 1 and I touch the select field, item one is already selected instead of zero but without touching the field it still shows one of the old values.